# List unique values and concatenate adjacent cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

```
=unique(Sheet2!D2:D)
```

How can I concatenate the content of the adjacent cell in E2:E (only for unique values of D2:D)?

Comment: Thought it did. My fault I only tried on Spreadsheets

Comment: To clarify - do you want to concatenate the content of adjacent cells for every occurrence of a value?

Comment: Content of the adjacent cells is the same for cells with same content in D:D.

Answer (score 1):

In F1 paste the `=unique(Sheet2!D2:D)`, and on G1 below, do a VLOOKUP for the value in E.

Eg.

`=F1&VLOOKUP(F1,$D$1:$E,2,false)` then drag down.

Or with arrayFormula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(F1:F&VLOOKUP(F1:F,$D$1:$E,2,false))`